# can't extracti href and title with beautifoulsoap

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have some html code and I need extract tittle and href for some categories in a class. The html is:

```
<div class="submenu_img3" >
                <ul class="submenu_list3 visible_false">
                        <li class="">

                <input type="hidden" name="has_subcategories" value="0"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="has_thirdlevel" value="0"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="level" value="0"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="posicion" value="0"/>
                <a href="https://www.alimentacion.alcampo.es/tienda/index.php?cPath=2112_13_1302_6511">
                    <span class="txt" >
                        Cerdo selecta                       </span>
                </a>
            </li>
                            <li class="">

                <input type="hidden" name="has_subcategories" value="0"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="has_thirdlevel" value="0"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="level" value="2"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="posicion" value="1"/>
                <a href="https://www.alimentacion.alcampo.es/tienda/index.php?cPath=2112_13_1302_130201">
                    <span class="txt" >
                        Cerdo Blanco                        </span>
                </a>
            </li>
                            <li class="">

                <input type="hidden" name="has_subcategories" value="0"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="has_thirdlevel" value="0"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="level" value="2"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="posicion" value="2"/>
                <a href="https://www.alimentacion.alcampo.es/tienda/index.php?cPath=2112_13_1302_130202">
                    <span class="txt" >
                        Cerdo de Teruel                     </span>
                </a>
            </li>
                            <li class="">

                <input type="hidden" name="has_subcategories" value="0"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="has_thirdlevel" value="0"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="level" value="2"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="posicion" value="3"/>
                <a href="https://www.alimentacion.alcampo.es/tienda/index.php?cPath=2112_13_1302_130203">
                    <span class="txt" >
                        Cerdo Ibérico                       </span>
                </a>
            </li>
```

But with these code I cant get anything:

```
for row in soup.find_all('div',attrs={"class" : "submenu_img3"}, href=True):
    print row.text
    print row.a['href']
```

Could you help me please? Thanks and sorry for my English!

Comment: So basically `soup.find_all('div',attrs={"class" : "submenu_img3"}, href=True)` finds zero items?

Comment: Yes, the html is longer but I've extracted a little piece

Comment: What without the `href` argument? Just `soup.find_all("div'". class_="submenu_img3")

Comment: Without href argument says me an error...typeerror: nonetype object has no attribute getitem

Comment: If I delete savings print also. It shows me the title ok: cerdo selecta,....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that your intent is to get the href and text for all the a tags within all the div tags with class submenu_img3. The issue with the find_all is the href attribute. The code is asking beautifulsoup to find all the div tags with href property, but there is none in the HTML.

I find it much easier to use select call which allows CSS selectors. Here is the code for finding all the a tags within div tag of class submenu_imgg3

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
for row in soup.select('div.submenu_img3 a'):
    print "Text:", row.text.strip()
    print "Href:", row['href']
```

Complete Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<div class="submenu_img3" >
    <ul class="submenu_list3 visible_false">
        <li class="">
            <input type="hidden" name="has_subcategories" value="0"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="has_thirdlevel" value="0"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="level" value="0"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="posicion" value="0"/>
            <a href="https://www.alimentacion.alcampo.es/tienda/index.php?cPath=2112_13_1302_6511">
                <span class="txt" > Cerdo selecta </span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="">
            <input type="hidden" name="has_subcategories" value="0"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="has_thirdlevel" value="0"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="level" value="2"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="posicion" value="1"/>
            <a href="https://www.alimentacion.alcampo.es/tienda/index.php?cPath=2112_13_1302_130201">
                <span class="txt" > Cerdo Blanco</span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="">
            <input type="hidden" name="has_subcategories" value="0"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="has_thirdlevel" value="0"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="level" value="2"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="posicion" value="2"/>
            <a href="https://www.alimentacion.alcampo.es/tienda/index.php?cPath=2112_13_1302_130202">
                <span class="txt" > Cerdo de Teruel </span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="">
            <input type="hidden" name="has_subcategories" value="0"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="has_thirdlevel" value="0"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="level" value="2"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="posicion" value="3"/>
            <a href="https://www.alimentacion.alcampo.es/tienda/index.php?cPath=2112_13_1302_130203">
                <span class="txt" > Cerdo Ibérico  </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
for row in soup.select('div.submenu_img3 a'):
    print "Text:", row.text.strip()
    print "Href:", row['href']
```

See W3C link for CSS selectors. CSS selectors are very powerful

```
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp
```